# Sort by # of Opportunity Contact Roles

Tags: data

Is there a way for me to find out which opportunities have more than one opportunity contact roles that are primary?  Unfortunately when I try to use grouping on report to do this, there are two many records and SF says it cannot do the sort.  Other ideas?

Comment: I see a radio button for choosing primary contact role in opportunity contact role edit page. Can we have more than one primary opportunity contact role for any given opportunity? Or I misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 1):

Since Opportunity Contact Roles do not support triggers, workflows, and other automation, I would use [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) in Scheduled mode to summarize this information.

You'd create a rollup of type Count from `OpportunityContactRole` to `Opportunity`, with the filter `IsPrimary = true`. You can set it to run on a nightly basis.

The rollup will put that count into a Number field on your Opportunity. You can then execute reports against that field on the Opportunity.

Comment: Anyway to do it without installing that package.  I just need to do it once.  Can I write a query to get the information?

Comment: @user57017
SOQL have limitation for number of records you can return... A better way would be export that report and do it in excel if its a one time thing.

Comment: Or use Data Loader to do the export, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what query you're running right now, so I hope I'm not suggesting the same one! But you can try something like this in the Dev Console:

`SELECT OpportunityId,Count(ContactId) FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE IsPrimary = true GROUP BY OpportunityId HAVING COUNT(ContactId) >1`

On an instance with ~100k OpportunityContactRoles, this runs pretty quickly.